# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'full_data' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm new to programming. I'm supposed to make a function that reads only dates and temperatures from the file. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

```
def read_data(text):
    data = open(text, 'r')
    for line in data:
        split_data = line.split(',')
        if line.isdigit():
            date = split_data[1]
            temperature = split_data[2]
            full_data = date + temperature
        data.close
    return full_data
max_dates, max_temps = read_data('DeBiltTempMax2022.txt')
```

this is the sample of the text file:

```
  EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on 23-05-2022
THESE DATA CAN BE USED FREELY PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED:

Klein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface
air temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.
Int. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.
Data and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu

FILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE IS -9999):

01-06 SOUID: Source identifier
08-15 DATE : Date YYYYMMDD
17-21 TX   : maximum temperature in 0.1 &#176;C
23-27 Q_TX : Quality code for TX (0='valid'; 1='suspect'; 9='missing')

This is the blended series of station NETHERLANDS, DE BILT (STAID: 162).
Blended and updated with sources: 100522 906260 
See file sources.txt and stations.txt for more info.

 SOUID,    DATE,   TX, Q_TX
100522,19010101,  -24,    0
100522,19010102,  -14,    0
100522,19010103,   -6,    0
100522,19010104,  -11,    0
100522,19010105,  -20,    0
100522,19010106,  -80,    0
100522,19010107,  -68,    0
100522,19010108,   -7,    0
100522,19010109,   44,    0
100522,19010110,   61,    0
100522,19010111,   51,    0
100522,19010112,  -20,    0
100522,19010113,  -20,    0
100522,19010114,   31,    0
100522,19010115,   54,    0
100522,19010116,   42,    0
100522,19010117,   65,    0
100522,19010118,   43,    0
100522,19010119,   64,    0
```

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: In your file, no `line` is ever a _digit_ (looking at the image you posted, all the lines have, at least, commas and things like that), so the block under `if line.isdigit()` is never run (because `isdigit()` will always return `False`), so `full_data = date + temperature` is never run, therefore, the `full_data` variable doesn't exist when you try to `return` it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with this code, I thought I would document them while re-writing it, however I am not sure what your code is exactly supposed to do.

```
def read_data(text):

    data_file = open(text, 'r')


    '''Data is not being read, you would first have to
       read the data and get it into a specific format
       to use it in what one is trying to accomplish'''

    data = data_file.read().splitlines()

    data_file.close()
    # we can close the file here since we don't need it anymore
    # also we have to put parentheses () in the end

    dates = []
    temperatures = []
    # variables we will use to store our data

    for line in data:
        '''
        the isdigit() function only works if
        the string consists of all digits

        the string should execlude everything including spaces

        there are multiple methods to validate and here we can check
        if the first char is a digit.
        '''

        try:

            if line[0].isdigit():
                # isdigit() function only works if the string
                # has nothing except for numbers not even spaces
                # strip() function removes spaces by default
                # from the sides unless explicitly provided a parameter

                split_data = line.split(',')

                # ['100522', '19010101', '  -24', '    0']
                # notice how they are strings and have spaces?
                # we convert these into digits

                split_data = [int(string) for string in split_data]
                # this is a single liner, takes each string in split_data
                # converts it to a integer

                date = split_data[1]
                temperature = split_data[2]

                dates.append(date)
                temperatures.append(temperature)

        except Exception as err:

            ''' index error : due to empty line '''
            print ('Errno:', err)


    if data != [] or temperatures != []:
        return dates, temperatures

    else:
        return [None, None] # default value

max_dates, max_temps = read_data('DeBiltTempMax2022.txt')
# Oh yes and most important of all, use meaningful variables,
# I am not sure whether max here implying everything or the highest value
# Also the parameter text in the read_data function could be 'text_file', since the reader cannot be sure whether its a string of data or filename.
```

Comment: `with open(...)` would be better here in case something fails during reading or splitting to avoid keeping open handle. And `.append` should be in general preferred to `+= [something]` to avoid creating intermediate list (it is inefficient). Also, previous `except` block should handle an exception (e.g. log it, `print` something, etc.) instead of silently discarding.

Comment: Good changes, I tried sticking to the format of the original script as it questioner would have a better time reading and understanding, otherwise it might be a new concept without the previous simpler one being clear, since the questioner seems new. I have made the log changes and append as well.

Comment: And `line[0]` is always a single character or an IndexError, and `''.isdigit()` is false, so `strip` is not necessary.

Comment: @SUTerliakov my OCD,  for using the `strip()`

Answer (score -1):

`return full_data`
here you are a returning a variable full_data whether or not it has been declared and set to a value
the if statement controlls that behavior.
so either:

```
def read_data(text):
    data = open(text, 'r')
    for line in data:
        split_data = line.split(',')
        if line.isdigit():
            date = split_data[1]
            temperature = split_data[2]
            full_data = date + temperature
            data.close
            return full_data
        data.close
        return #whatever default val here
max_dates, max_temps = read_data('DeBiltTempMax2022.txt')
```

or set a default  right after reading the file

Comment: I downvote, because this clearly does not fix the code in question, although attempts to answer the question. `for...return` is definitely not compatible with "read_data" function name, since it returns only first matching row, and `data.close` is an attribute access instead of method call. Again, it somewhat answers the question, so I'm basically saying "well, it is still obviously wrong, bad code, which should never appear in good answers".